# Inserting new record into table if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I want to insert into my MySQL Workbench database in my python script but I am having issues trying to get it to only insert once if a certain value already exist. So lets say I'm inserting names and the name 'Bob' is already in the DB, I don't want to insert it again at this point.

I've been looking at other resources and am currently trying:

```
for account in accounts:
        sql = ("If Not Exists(SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Account_Name = " + str(account) + ") "
                "Begin "
                "INSERT into Accounts (Account_Name, Account_ID, Formatted_Name, Crawler_Name) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) "
                "End")
        val = (account, '0', 'test', 'test')
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
mydb.commit()
```

where account is some string that isn't relevant here. I basically want to insert account into the database but only once, if it runs again and the same account is found, I don't want to re-insert the duplicate (which a regular insert statement will do).

The error I get is:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'If Not Exists(SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Account_Name = DE - Kipling DE) Begin' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `INSERT IGNORE` which will ignore the fact that the DB will try to complain about `Duplicate entry`. See [here](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/#using-insert-ignore) for more. In the link you can read about other strategies (which you may find more suitable for your needs)

Comment: Ah yes, i had tried this before but just realized i set the wrong column as a unique. Setting the account_name column as unique solves my issue, thanks!